# How to backup my site and restore my wordpress site

Tags: database, backup

My site, http://www.forerunnerintl.org is down hard. It looks like a problem with Wordpress. I want to back up my posts, etc. and then wipe everything and restore it to a fresh wordpress instance.

Googling for backup and restore wordpress instance generated a zillion pages, but most are for backing up using a plugin or backing up all of the themes and everything else, which I wish to dump.

Some docs say my posts are stored in MySQL databases, but where? I haven't found them.

Also, I want to have a normal website for my root and move wordpress to a subdirectory when I pave and nuke the site.

So how do I backup just my posts and restore them in the new wordpress instance?

Comment: Themes are generally stored in the `wp-content/themes` directory. The database only holds the name of the theme currently in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this SELECT * FROM databasename.wp_posts in mysql to view all your post; Then export it and then on the new database you can import the post.

Comment: OK, where's the wp_posts file?

Comment: Wp_posts isn't a file. It's a table. You would need to login to your providers cPanel (or equivalent) and use the DB admin tool to run the query.

Comment: For windows server: go to mysql and click on your database and expand the databse, you would see the wp_post table

Answer (score 1):

Following the link you provided, I found the error message:
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_Post in /home/forerunn/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php on line 22`

First, I would not assume it's a corrupted database. (If it is, you can usually access the database through PHPmyadmin; that's how you would backup the database, all of it or select tables.)

Recall what you did right before you discovered the error. Did you add new plugins? Update Wordpress? Try to undo any changes to see if things work again. Then google that error message and see if any of the results match your situation.

Comment: So, I see two databases blah_main and blah_wrdp1. Do I need both of these?

Comment: I wouldn't know without browsing through them both, but I would think "wrdp1" is short for "wordpress1". I would look for the wp_posts table there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free migration plugins

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: Not looking for a plugin